Spring Integration : Poller.fixedDealy not working as expected in multithreaded application
I have created an application using Spring Integration. It reads from the database converts the rows into XML format and sends it to Kafka.
I have used Executor to create Multiple threads for transformation and handlers.
I am using poller.FixedDelay, polling happens even before the first set of results are processed. It's not waiting for the process to finish.
Maybe because of multi-threading? What else can I use to ensure the next poll happens only when the first set of results has been processed?

The new polling task with a fixedDelay is scheduled when the previous one has been finished. If you use executors downstream, then the current task is finished exactly at the moment when it is placed to that separate thread.
So, there is no easy way for you to achieve what you want if you just try to rely on the fixedDelay, but still use new threads downstream.
You probably can achieve a requirement with an AtomicBoolean which you set to true when you done with the current process downstream. And then consult with its state in the ReceiveMessageAdvice.beforeReceive(). And probably reset it in the afterReceive().
See more info in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/polling-consumer.html#smart-polling
